# Passing Apple App Store Connect Review with Google or Apple sign in

Tags: ios, flutter, deployment

I have an app that allows you to sign in through Apple or Google.

I created an google account that doesn't require 2-step verification, however they review was still not able to get in.

How can I create a dummy email or Apple ID that the reviewer can use to sign in during the Apple app store review?

Comment: This depends a lot more on your app's backend than the app itself. Do you use firebase, a custom server, or what?